# Text of JLabel out of bounds

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlabel

I'm trying to create a custom `JLabel` with the outline effect this is my code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class OutlineLabel extends JLabel {

    private Color outlineColor = Color.BLACK;
    private Color fillColor = Color.WHITE;


    public OutlineLabel() {
        super();

    }
    public void setThin(int thin){
        //this.thin=thin;
    }
    public OutlineLabel(String text,Color inline,Color outline) {
        super(text);
        outlineColor=outline;
        fillColor=inline;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        String text = getText();

        BasicStroke outlineStroke = new BasicStroke(1.5f);

        if (g instanceof Graphics2D) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            // remember original settings
            Color originalColor = g2.getColor();
            Stroke originalStroke = g2.getStroke();
            RenderingHints originalHints = g2.getRenderingHints();


            // create a glyph vector from your text
            GlyphVector glyphVector=g.getFont().layoutGlyphVector(g2.getFontRenderContext(),text.toCharArray(),0,text.length(),Font.LAYOUT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

            // get the shape object
            Shape textShape = glyphVector.getOutline();

            // activate effects
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

           //g.translate(getX(), getY()+160);
            g2.setColor(outlineColor);
            g2.setStroke(outlineStroke);
            g2.draw(textShape); // draw outline

            g2.setColor(fillColor);
            g2.fill(textShape); // fill the shape

            // reset to original settings after painting
            g2.setColor(originalColor);
            g2.setStroke(originalStroke);
            g2.setRenderingHints(originalHints);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame w = new JFrame();
        w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Font myFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,146);
        OutlineLabel label = new OutlineLabel("TEST",Color.red,Color.yellow);
        label.setFont(myFont);
        JPanel p=new JPanel();
        p.add(label);
        w.setContentPane(p);
        w.pack();
        w.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the text is drawn outside the bounds of the components... I would like to understand why and how to fix this, you can verify that remove the comment from :

```
g.translate(getX(), getY()+160);
```

The text is well drawn, but this is no acceptable because the label has to be used in a more complex layout and multiple times, I cannot translate every time the coordinate basing on the label position, I need a more generic solution.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Override `getPreferredSize().`

Comment: Overriding getPreferredSize doesn't make any difference...

Comment: I don't see your implementation. Why not add a `Border` to the enclosing `Container`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it, what do you mean? (I have edited the question removing the borderLayout that was not necessary )

Comment: JLabel is a poor choice for this, as it has capabilities to support icons and alignment

Comment: I would like to have labeled components in my app with all the lables having outline effect, what do you suggest as alternatives?

Comment: As a "general" recommendation I'd suggest either a simple `JComponent` or `JPanel`. You're going to need to do some work calculating the "actual" size of the component, but once you've converted the text to a `Shape` it wouldn't be that hard

Comment: Ok I will give it a try, but I still don't understand why Y coordinates are wrong in the example I have posted.

Comment: I have tried to extends Component instead of Label but the result is the same, the text is drawn outside the bound... You can easily verify with the code I have posted just changing the parent of the class (and adapt it a little bit just adding a text field in the class...) I'm confused!

Comment: All you guys were wrong, I found a solution and I have replied on my original post. In any case many thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found a solution for that.
If somebody else have the same problem:
I don't know why but calling:

```
Shape textShape = glyphVector.getOutline();
```

the textShape is automatic translated up of the height of the shape itself.
So it goes out of bounds. If you want to put it back in the center of the component (Vertical Alignment) you need a AffineTransform. In the example I have posted before is enough to replace this line :

```
g.translate(getX(), getY()+160);
```

with these:

```
int heightComponent=getHeight();
int heightShape=(int)textShape.getBounds().getHeight();
final AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(
                  0,heightShape+((int)heightComponent/2-heightShape/2));
textShape=transform.createTransformedShape(textShape);
```

N.B. The comments on my first post are completely wrong. You can extends Label, no problem at all...  and you don't need to override the getPreferredSize , setting the preferred size from outside the class is enough.